# Copy local directory into docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-volume

I have succesfully created a volume (/code in the container) which holds django app (/web locally). When I spin up the dev environment, I want to have a folder (holding dummy data) available within the container, but I want to COPY the data, not have it as a VOLUME (so that if it's deleted in the container, it's not deleted from my local file system).

Folder structure:

```
...
docker-compose.yml
docker-compose.dev.yml
webms/
  data/
    folder/
      subdir1/
        file1
      subdir2/
  web/
  Dockerfile
...
```

docker-compose.yml

```
...
services:
  web:
    volumes:
          - ./webms/web:/code
        build:
          context: ./webms
...
```

docker-compose.dev.yml

```
...
services:
  web:
    volumes:
          - ./webms/data/folder:/code/folder
...
```

Dockerfile

```
...
WORKDIR /code
ADD ./web/ .
COPY ./data/folder/ ./folder/
...
```

I can add `data/folder` as a volume succesfully, but then changes in the container reflect on my file system.

If remove the `volumes` directive from docker-compose.dev.yml, `volumes` in docker-compose.yml overwrites `/code` in the container and `/folder` is not longer available.

If I remove all the `volumes` directives, all the files are there, but changes to code in `/web` isn't live anymore (have to restart the container each time).

How do I copy `data/folder` into the container and have it available every time I restart the container / have a copy of the local file system copied into the volume? It may not be possible.

I have looked at similar answers on SO and they don't address this case.

Comment: Since you `ADD` the code into your image in the Dockerfile, you don't need either `volumes:` block and I'd delete them both.

Comment: Thanks @DavidMaze. If I remove `volumes:`, any changes to code locally (in `web/`) won't be reflected in the container until it's restarted...

Comment: Correct, Docker images are normally immutable.  You might use a host-based development environment for day-to-day development work before packaging your application in an image.

Comment: (For parallels you might look at Node's `node_modules` library directory: Node stores an application's library tree in a subdirectory of the application, so if you bind-mount a host directory over the application source tree it hides the image's library tree.  There's a common hack of using an anonymous volume here, but it's not perfect.)

Comment: I took some time to clear my head. Instead of copying `/data` into the volume `/web`, I've just copied data into it's own directory.